# Why is `throw` operator exported with an underscore

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I usually use static creation operators without `Observable` like this:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

const o = of(1, 2, 3);
```

It is possible because `rxjs` package exports each operator separately:

```
import { ArrayObservable } from './ArrayObservable';
export declare const of: typeof ArrayObservable.of;
```

However, `throw` operator is exported with and underscore:

```
import { ErrorObservable } from './ErrorObservable';
export declare const _throw: typeof ErrorObservable.create;
```

So I have to reference it like this:

```
import { _throw } from 'rxjs/observable/throw';

const o = _throw(new Error('some error data'));
```

Can anyone explain the reason for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`throw` is a [reserved keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw), just like `return`, `if` or `for`. You cannot name variables or functions like that.

Comment: makes sense, thanks. need to wait another 6 minutes to accept the answer)